# Redis zRevRange Leaderboard

Tags: redis

I have created a simple leaderboard application in C#. However I noticed a problem with pulling and ordering scores. Lets say I run ZREVRANGE on a sorted set (95, 12, 60, 50, 66) then it will return in the order 95, 66, 60, 50, 12. Great that's exactly what I want.

However if I add 100 to that same order set, ZREVRANGE return 95, 66, 60, 50, 12, 100. It places 100 at the end of the set, even though it is greater than the other numbers. After sum digging, I was able to find out that ZREVRANGE returns a jagged array of bytes. From what I can tell, it is in order based upon the first digit in the number Which is the first number in the jagged array. Here is an example.

[image]

As you can see it looks like it is ordering based. Should I be using something different then ZREVRANGE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordered sets use a score for ordering. Members are ordered lexicographically if they have the same score.

It looks like you're using members to store the leaderboard's scores, and I'm betting you set the score for all members to the same value. Besides yielding the unexpected, but correct, lexicographical ordering, this also means you won't be able to store the same score more than once.

Comment: Thank you, I found out that it was a problem when I was inserting the data. Instead of inserting the value and the score, I was just inserting the value. Because the score was null for all of them, it wasn't being put in the right order.